# Javascript spread & inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, spread-syntax

I am fairly new to javascript development and still learning concepts. I have a question regarding the spread "operator" (`...`).
Can it be used as an inheritance-like mechanism or does it have side effects that should make me avoid this ?

**Example**

```
const A = {
  prop1: "value1",
  prop2: function() {return this.prop1}
}

const B = {
  ...A,
  prop1: "updated_value1",
  prop3: "value3"
}
```

B here can be seen has being inherited from A, `A.prop2()` returns `value1`, and `B.prop2()` returns `updated_value1` has one would expect from any inherited object.

Is this valid ?

Comment: It is throwing error

Comment: No. `B` does not contain `A`'s `prototype` chain when using the spread syntax, only its own properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you posted is working as expected, as properties from A are copied to B. However, this is not an example of inheritance, it's just a shallow copy.

In your example all properties are primitives, consider what happens if we add a reference to A:

```
const A = {
  prop1: "value1",
  prop2: function() {return this.prop1},
  obj: { value: 1 }
}

const B = {
  ...A,
  prop1: "updated_value1",
  prop3: "value3"
}
```

Now, changing `A.obj.value` will also modify `B.obj.value` which will essentially make all B's to share their `obj` with A and among themselves. This could be useful in some situations, but it's not exactly inheritance.

For inheritance it's best to use ["Javascript classes"](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Answer (score 1):

You can't really call it inherence. It's a merge. By writing this

```
const B = {
  ...A,
  prop1: "updated_value1",
  prop3: "value3"
}
```

`props1` from  A will be overwritten by `prop1` from B. So yes, `B.prop2()` will return `updated_value1` and it's completely fair.

Comment: Yes, try in the Chrome console.

Answer (score 1):

In your case I would tend to use Object Assign since less things can go wrong:

```
const A = {
  prop1: "value1",
  prop2: function() {return this.prop1}
}

cont B = Object.assign(A, {
  prop1: "updated_value1",
  prop3: "value3"
});
```

But still this is no real inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

It might look like inheritance but in fact all you are defining there is :

```
const A = {
  prop1: "value1",
  prop2: function() {return this.prop1}
}

const B = {
  prop1: "value1",
  prop2: function() {return this.prop1},
  prop1: "updated_value1",
  prop3: "value3"
}
```

In essence you are overriding the member defined 2 lines up for object B.
It is not inheritance because the definition of the members will be owned by object B instead of a prototype of B for example. When referring to B.prop1 the engine will not have to look on prototypes for the property, which is what inheritance would do if you were using protos

Answer (score 0):

I will not call this inheritance.Using the spread operator with object is similar to use Object.assign().This method what it does is to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object.
See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Answer (score 0):

{...A} simply creates a copy of all the key-values from 'A' and sets it to 'B'.
Then you update the property prop1 of 'B' to updated_value1. 'A' remains unchanged. This is completely valid